# How does AWK define a line?

Tags: regex, logging, awk

I was trying to parse a log file using AWK,

test.log

```
[12/12/18 11:54:54:321 PST] 0000077c WC_SERVER     < com.ibm.commerce.server.HttpRequestWrapper setAttribute(String,Object) Exit
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO < -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.createContextSPI(ActivityToken, ActivityData, String) Exit
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext : [bInitialize = false][bRecalibrate = false][inCallerId = null][inRunAsId = null][inStoreId = null][istrChannelId = null][bDirty = false][bRequestStarted = false][iOriginalSerializedString = null][iToken = null]
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.loadContextData(ActivityToken, String) Entry
                                 68884:false:false:0
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextservice.commands.ContextDataSerValueCacheCmdImpl.myPerformExecute() Entry
                                 68884
```

the idea is, if a line starts with `[`, and it matches the pattern, then print out the line and also the following line, which does not start with `[`.

Expected result:

```
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO < -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.createContextSPI(ActivityToken, ActivityData, String) Exit
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext : [bInitialize = false][bRecalibrate = false][inCallerId = null][inRunAsId = null][inStoreId = null][istrChannelId = null][bDirty = false][bRequestStarted = false][iOriginalSerializedString = null][iToken = null]
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.loadContextData(ActivityToken, String) Entry
                                 68884:false:false:0
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextservice.commands.ContextDataSerValueCacheCmdImpl.myPerformExecute() Entry
                                 68884
```

AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1; flag = 0;}{ if($0 ~ /^\[/){if($0 ~ /WC_BUSINESSCO/){flag=1}else{flag = 0}; if(flag==1){print $0}}}' test.log
```

Current output:

```
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO < -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.createContextSPI(ActivityToken, ActivityData, String) Exit
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.loadContextData(ActivityToken, String) Entry
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextservice.commands.ContextDataSerValueCacheCmdImpl.myPerformExecute() Entry
```

As you can see lines that don't start with `[` aren't printed; after some debugging, it seems that AWK believes the issue lines is part or the pattern matched line. It's not printing out due to wrap issue, I guess.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overdoing it.

```
awk '/^\[/{p=/WC_BUSINESSCO/}p' test.log
```

- `/^\[/` means perform the following action (`{...}`) if current record begins with a `[`,
- `p=/WC_BUSINESSCO/` sets `p` true if current record contains `WC_BUSINESSCO` and vice versa,
- `p` at the end means print current record if `p` is true.
- if the current line does *not* start with `[`, then the `p` value from the *previous* line remains.

For further information, see `man awk`.

For clarity, some additional whitespace:

```
awk '
    /^\[/ { p = /WC_BUSINESSCO/ }
    p
' test.log
```

Comment: Hi @oguzismail, it is working, can you please explain your code a bit? I'm new to AWK, I don't understand the usage of `p` parameter.

Comment: @Ian, have a read through the [awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) and see if that give you some understanding.

Comment: @glennjackman jackman thanks for your help, I review my own logic, compared to your suggestion, it turns out that I miss out the last if block. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This only works if WC_BUSINESSCO is always in the first line.

Comment: @kvantour yes,that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

**How does awk define a line?**

Awk does not have any knowledge of what a line is. Awk knows the concept *records* and *fields*.

Files are split in *records* where consecutive records are split by the record separator `RS`. Each record is split in fields, where consecutive fields are split by the field separator `FS`.

By default, the record separator `RS` is set to be the <newline> character (`\n`) and thus each record is a line. The record separator has the following definition:

> **`RS`:**
>   The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

**How can I now define a multi-line record?**

For multi-line records where the start of a record cannot uniquely be identified by a single character, you might want to make use of `gawk` or any awk version where `RS` is can be multiple characters (or a regular expression). In case of the OP, you can define `RS` as `\n\[`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\[" }/WC_BUSINESSCO/ { print (NR==1 ? "" : "[") $0 }' file
```

If you do not have access to such a version of awk, and you have to stick to POSIX, you can do:

```
awk '/^\[/ && (rec ~ /WC_BUSINESSCO/) { printf rec; } # process record
     /^\[/ { rec="" }                                 # initialise record
     { rec = rec $0 ORS }                             # build record
     END { if (rec ~ /WC_BUSINESSCO/) printf rec }    # process last record
    ' file
```

This will match "WC_BUSINESSCO" in the full record, and not only the first line as is done in most solutions here. While for the OP, the first line might be enough. More general questions might have a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

You said: *then print out the line and **also the following line***.

Try this instead:

```
awk '/^\[.*WC_BUSINESSCO/{print;getline;print}' test.log
```

The flow is quite simple when the pattern matches print the line, get the next one and print again.

To get all the lines after the one that starts with `[`:

```
awk '/^\[/{i=0}/WC_BUSINESSCO/{i=1}i' test.log
```

Check [this](https://klashxx.github.io/awk-between-two-patterns).

Comment: you're right @oguzismail, The question says: *also the following line* so I answered with that assumption in mind.

Answer (score 1):

with GNU-`awk` you can define the record separator as you specified

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)\\[' '/WC_BUSINESSCO/{print RT $0}' file
```

with the pattern match print the record (possibly multi-line), but with the record separator prefixed to the record.

with other `awk`s the workaround

```
$ awk '/^\[/{if(/WC_BUSINESSCO/){print; p=1} else p=0} p&&!/^\[/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl, then this is a generic solution based on your requirements.
Note that it doesn't hard-code any text (e.g WC_BUSINESSCO ) from the file for the solution.

```
/tmp> cat test.log
[12/12/18 11:54:54:321 PST] 0000077c WC_SERVER     < com.ibm.commerce.server.HttpRequestWrapper setAttribute(String,Object) Exit
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO < -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.createContextSPI(ActivityToken, ActivityData, String) Exit
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext : [bInitialize = false][bRecalibrate = false][inCallerId = null][inRunAsId = null][inStoreId = null][istrChannelId = null][bDirty = false][bRequestStarted = false][iOriginalSerializedString = null][iToken = null]
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.loadContextData(ActivityToken, String) Entry
                                 68884:false:false:0
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextservice.commands.ContextDataSerValueCacheCmdImpl.myPerformExecute() Entry
                                 68884
/tmp> perl -ne ' print "$t$p" if $x and /^\[/ ;if(!/^\[/) { $x++;$t.=$p} if(/^\[/) { $x=0;$t=""} $p=$_;END { print "$t$p" if $x }' test.log
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO < -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.createContextSPI(ActivityToken, ActivityData, String) Exit
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext : [bInitialize = false][bRecalibrate = false][inCallerId = null][inRunAsId = null][inStoreId = null][istrChannelId = null][bDirty = false][bRequestStarted = false][iOriginalSerializedString = null][iToken = null]
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextserviceimpl.BusinessContextServiceImpl.loadContextData(ActivityToken, String) Entry
                                 68884:false:false:0
                                 com.ibm.commerce.context.base.BaseContext
[12/12/18 11:54:54:328 PST] 0000077c WC_BUSINESSCO > -1112ef1b:16732963f15:-7fd4 com.ibm.commerce.component.contextservice.commands.ContextDataSerValueCacheCmdImpl.myPerformExecute() Entry
                                 68884
/tmp>
```